# Tkinter calculator, can only do 1 operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, calculator

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

import sys

top=tkinter.Tk()    
from tkinter import*



def clear():
    e1.delete(0,END)
    return
def seven():
    v.set(v.get()+str("7"))
    v.get()
def eight():
    v.set(v.get()+str("8"))
    v.get()
def nine():
    v.set(v.get()+str("9"))
    v.get()
def four():
    v.set(v.get()+str("4"))
    v.get()
def five():
    v.set(v.get()+str("5"))
    v.get()
def six():
    v.set(v.get()+str("6"))
    v.get()
def one():
    v.set(v.get()+str("1"))
    v.get()
def two():
    v.set(v.get()+str("2"))
    v.get()
def three():
    v.set(v.get()+str("3"))
    v.get()
def zero():
    v.set(v.get()+str("0"))
    v.get()
def add():
    global op1
    op1=v.get()
    e1.delete(0,END)
def equals():
    v.set(int(op1)+int(v.get()))
    v.get()




top.title("D & R Calculator")
top.geometry("290x240")
from tkinter import*
frame=Frame(top)
frame.grid(column=0,row=0)
framenum=Frame(top,height=265)
framenum.grid()
v=StringVar()



from tkinter import*
e1=Entry(frame,width=30,textvariable=v)
e1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W+E)

b7=tkinter.Button(framenum,text="7",height=3,width=9,command=seven)
b7.grid(row=0,column=1)

b8=tkinter.Button(framenum,text="8",height=3,width=9,command=eight)
b8.grid(row=0,column=2)

b9=tkinter.Button(framenum,text="9",height=3,width=9,command=nine)
b9.grid(row=0,column=3)

b4=tkinter.Button(framenum,text="4",height=3,width=9,command=four)
b4.grid(row=1,column=1)

b5=tkinter.Button(framenum,text="5",height=3,width=9,command=five)
b5.grid(row=1,column=2)

b6=tkinter.Button(framenum,text="6",height=3,width=9,command=six)

b6.grid(row=1,column=3)

b1=tkinter.Button(framenum,text="1",height=3,width=9,command=one)
b1.grid(row=2,column=1)

b2=tkinter.Button(framenum,text="2",height=3,width=9,command=two)
b2.grid(row=2,column=2)

b3=tkinter.Button(framenum,text="3",height=3,width=9,command=three)
b3.grid(row=2,column=3)

b0=tkinter.Button(framenum,text="0",height=3,width=9,command=zero)
b0.grid(row=3,column=2)


f1=tkinter.Button(framenum,text="+",height=3,width=9,command=add)
f1.grid(row=2,column=4)

f2=tkinter.Button(framenum,text="-",height=3,width=9)
f2.grid(row=1,column=4)

f3=tkinter.Button(framenum,text="X",height=3,width=9)
f3.grid(row=0,column=4)

f4=tkinter.Button(framenum,text="/",height=3,width=9)
f4.grid(row=3,column=4)


eq=tkinter.Button(framenum,text="=",height=3,width=9,command=equals)
eq.grid(row=3,column=3)
c=tkinter.Button(framenum,text="CE",height=3,width=9,command=clear)
c.grid(row=3,column=1)


top.mainloop
```

I challenged myself to make a tkinter calculator WITHOUT using a tutorial. I've finally made it work but there is one problem. It can only do one function. Be it addition,multiplication,division or taking away it can only do one operation.All I want to know is how would I make the calculator remember which button was pressed/ which command so it could differentiate between different functions. Basically, I need help or guidance in making the calculator do all operations, instead of just having it do one operations and having to manually go and edit it to make it do another operation. Help or even just a push in the right direction would be great, I am very new to Python.

Comment: your naming convention could also be better, but as long as you get it :)

Answer (score 0):

Alright so there are a few of things wrong with you code:

- You are missing the parentheses after `top.mainloop()`
- You have the line `from tkinter import *` heaps of times, this
  doesn't matter really, but  you only need it once at the top, and can
  do away with all the other imports at the top as well.
- You need to globalise `op1` in the `equals` function.
- You haven't written functions for the divide, subtract and multiply
  buttons, so how could they work? When I try 9 - 6 and hit equals I
  get a `NameError op1 is not defined` it tries to equal something but
  can't as the subtract button doesn't do anything yet.
- This means that you can only start with the adding button, so I try 5 + 4 and hit equals, which
  works sweet and gives me 9, but if you the try to minus 5 from the result it will put a 5 in the text box and add five again when you hit equals.
- When I try to start with 9 - 6 as mentioned earlier, it won't work. To get around this issue with how `op1` relates to adding, and in the `equals` function `op1` is used in a way it will only work for the `adding` function you need a `try/except` loop:

  ```
  def equals():
      try:
          v.set(int(op1)+int(v.get()))
          v.get()
          del op1
      except NameError:
          try:
              # Whatever needs to be written for subtraction to work
              # (using op2 as variable?) something like this:
              v.set(int(op2)-int(v.get()))
              v.get()
              del op2
          except NameError:
              try:
                  # etc. etc. until you have done all four equals methods...
  ```

  where `op2` is set in the subtracting function etc.

This should give you some help to be able to continue, if you want I can fix program for you, but only if you don't want to do it yourself?

Comment: Actually, When I try out your advice, a lot of unexpected indent errors come up. Any Idea why?

Comment: where are the unexpected indent errors, I've tried what I said and it works fine, I got the whole calculator working alright except the minor things like errors when you divide by zero, and try to make it fail.

Comment: I think the errors are just because I haven't finished the definition, once I've done it ; I think it should work.

Comment: @KhaganKhagan ok cool, get back to me if it doesn't work :). if you need i can show what i got, but you should be alright!